How to specify a delimiter and other parameters when exporting an RTC query
I am trying to export one of my RTC Queries from a script.
The export line I am using is:
https://<Server>/ccm//resource/itemOid/com.ibm.team.workitem.query.QueryDescriptor/<Query UIID>?_mediaType=text/csv

It works, but the output is tab-separated, not comma-separated.
How do I specify a comma delimiter? I've tried appending ?_delimiter=, but it didn't work. The rest of the default settings seem ok.
